# jQuery 1.3.2 adds sizset='' sizcache='' attributes on IE when I use .html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When I do $('div#tborder').html() I get following:

```
<DIV id=tborder style="BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; 
DISPLAY: block; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; 
BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; 
TEXT-ALIGN: left" sizcache="9" sizset="124">Some Text </div>
```

See the additional sizcache and sizset attributes are set. How can I get rid of these? This is a known bug in jQuery1.3.2 according to [this](http://www.mikepadgett.com/technology/technical/jquery-html-strange-results-ie-events/). Please see the comments in this article as well.

Original Code:

```
<DIV id=tborder style="BORDER: #000 1px solid;  
DISPLAY: block; FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; 
TEXT-ALIGN: left">Some Text </div>
```

Comment: Can you show how tborder looks like in the original HTML code? Does your code validate? The comments refer to this happening sometimes when a tag is not closed.

Comment: @pekka: original code is same excluding those 2 tags and code is xhtml validated.

Comment: I've temporarily hacked it using javascript RegExp function.

Comment: Which IE? Can't reproduce this in IE6. Please show a small working example which reproduces this. According to what I read until now it depends on call order, unclean html, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not good solution but I've temporarily hacked it using javascript RegExp function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use html? It seems to return a lot of useless attributes along with sizcache and sizset. If all you want is the text, then have a look at `text()` instead.

Comment: @Marius: I know text() is better option byt my div has another smaller div inside, which I've omitted for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotation marks around the id value.
`id=tborder` -> `id="tborder"`
Also make both div lower case. 
`<DIV> </div>` -> `<div></div>`

If those two things don't work. Then use `removeAttr().html()`.

```js
$( "#tborder" ).removeAttr("sizcache").removeAttr( "sizset" ).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a javascript error in your page, you will see these do not always get removed by the sizzle engine.  For instance, if you put a reference to a method/function in the window opener pages javascript function, and you did not open the page from that opener, you will see these.

for instance in this code, the opener is not present:

```
if (self.opener.panelNotes)
{
    self.opener.__doPostBack("panelNotes", "");
};
```

because I directly opened the window, and it was not opened by another window so no opener exists.  This gives a javascript error on the page

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;
>   OfficeLivePatch.0.0) Timestamp: Thu, 6
>   May 2010 15:15:16 UTC
>
> Message: 'self.opener.panelNotes' is
>   null or not an object Line: 278 Char:
>   9 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://localhost/prototype/Apps/SmartPrototype/Js/MarkPrototype.js